# Weak convergence of $\mu_n = \frac{1}{2n +1} \sum_{k=-n}^{n} \delta_{\frac{k}{n}}$

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence, uniform-distribution

Show that sequence of probabilities
$$
\mu_n = \frac{1}{2n +1} \sum_{k=-n}^{n} \delta_{\frac{k}{n}}
$$
converges weakly. To which probability?

Now, I've written down the first elements:
$$
\mu_1 = \frac{1}{3}(\delta_{-1} + \delta_{0} + \delta_{1})
$$
$$
\mu_2 = \frac{1}{5}(\delta_{-1} + \delta_{\frac{-1}{2}} + \delta_{0} +\delta_{\frac{1}{2}} + \delta_{1})
$$
and so on. It is a convex combination of Dirac's deltas which "denses" around $[-1, 1]$. It can't be $U(-1,1)$ because no irrational numbers will ever fall into $\mu_n$.

What probability is that? How can I show the weak convergence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: let $f\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a continuous and bounded function. Compute the limit $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)d\mu_n(x)$ by writing the integral as a Riemann sum:
$$
\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)d\mu_n(x)=\frac 1{2n+1}\sum_{k=-n}^nf\left(\frac kn\right).
$$

Comment: Something along these lines: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f(x) \mu_{{n}_{X}}(dx) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=-n}^{n} \frac{1}{2n+1} \mu_{\frac{i}{n}}(\frac{1}{2i+1})f(\frac{1}{2i+1})$ = $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2n+1} \sum_{i=-n}^{n}f(\frac{1}{2i+1}) = \text{ ?}$. What comes after the question mark? Is that $\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)d(\lambda \cap Q)$?

Comment: @math_beginner I edited in order to give a further hint.

Comment: And that is $\int f(x) d \mu$ with $\mu$ being $U(-1,1)$ indeed! I did not know we could approximate continuous probabilities with discrete ones that have finite atoms - but I have just seen a proof of something like that.